# Launch Screen may not have connections

Tags: xcode6.1

Getting this error while trying to compile and run app.
Since the only work I have done is on the XIB file, I have tried removing the value from the launch screen file box, still it didn't help.

Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4upM5.png

Using Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you set outlet connection with any of the object of launch screen then it's give this types of error.Simply launch screen has a plain(static) UI. You can not change it's value run time or using creating UIViewcontroller. So, remove all outlet connection of launch screen. If you want remove Launch Screen then go to General setting tab then clear value of Launch Screen file. Make sure it's also clear into the info.plist file.